# Change the Row Color Based on the Column value in CGridView

Tags: yii

In Yii, CGridView has it's own background color in the row. But what I want to do is highlight particular row based on the value of one of the column.

For Instance, I have three column, id, name, status. Now, If the Value of status is Inactive or 0, I should highlight the row with some color.

I read the class reference briefly and searched this site as well. But could not find the relevant solution. If some example or some direction toward the right solution, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ujjwal

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CGridView ['rowCssClassExpression'](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#rowCssClassExpression-detail) is the way to get what you want.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'rowCssClassExpression'=>'($data->myFlag==0)?"normal":"especial"',
    'columns'=>array(
    ...
    ),
));
```

You can also call a custom php function, and pass the $data variable to it. That function should return the class name for the given row :)

Comment: I was cursing yii/zii while I googled for this. Sorry for the 'right on!' comment, but I am feeling especially grateful for the easy fix.

Comment: @sucotronic I have `$data->created_at` which is timestamp, and I want highlight row `if($data-<created_at == $today`) and I have `$today = date('Y-m-d')` too. Is there any solution for such scenario?

Comment: @ersks you can use: `'rowCssClassExpression'=>'($data->created_at==date('Y-m-d'))?"highlight":""'`

Answer (score 1):

Use rowCssClass and rowCssClassExpression for your functionality. I did not tested this code but the trick you can use to get your solution.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'rowCssClass'=>array('odd','even'),
    'rowCssClassExpression'=>($data->status==0)?even:odd,
    'columns'=>array(
    ),
));
```

Comment: 'rowCssClass' and 'rowCssClassExpression' are [mutually exclusive](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php#505) :(

Comment: And also, while I try to use rowCssClassExpression value without the quotes, it does not work. The condition is always false. So, sucotronic is right!

Comment: I have said that I did not tested this code but the trick will work.

Comment: @OnkarJanwa I have `$data->created_at` which is timestamp, and I want highlight row `if($data-<created_at == $today`) and I have `$today = date('Y-m-d')` too. Is there any solution for such scenario?