# Dynamically Change the Row Color Based on the Column value in CGridView

Tags: php, ajax, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

First, actually I'm not using CGridView, but I'm using [TbExtendedGridView](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/extended-grid.html) from [YiiBooster](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/index.html). I use CGridView on the title because it's more familiar, but still these two things works in quite the same way.

I'm enabling inline edit on my TbExtendedGridView (TbJEditableColumn). TbExtendedGridView is using jquery's Jeditable for this functionality. This [Jeditable also applicable to CGridView](http://help.discretelogix.com/php/yii/enable-in-place-editing-in-yii-grid.htm).

Thanks to this SO's question: [Change the Row Color Based on the Column value in CGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077325/change-the-row-color-based-on-the-column-value-in-cgridview-in-yii)

I know how to change the row color. But, it's still not working with the inline edit functionality. So, my question is, how can that `rowCssClassExpression` be updated everytime I edit some value on a column?

This is my view's code on `[root]/protected/views/transaction/admin.php`

```
<?
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id'=>'transaction-grid',
    'rowCssClassExpression'=>'$data->getCssClass()',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'date',
            'value'=> 'date("j M Y", strtotime($data->date))',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:52px')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'amount',
            'value' => 'number_format($data->amount, 0, ",", ".")',
            'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'currency', 'style'=>'width:72px')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'category_name',
            'value'=>'$data->category->name',
            'header'=>'Category',
            'sortable' => 'true',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:131px'),
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbJEditableColumn',
            'jEditableOptions' => array(
                'type' => 'optgroup',
                'loadurl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/index.php/transaction/getCategory',
                'submitdata' => array('attribute'=>'category'),
                'cssclass' => 'form',
                'width' => '180px',
                'submit' => 'save changes'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'desc',
            'value'=>'$data->desc',
            'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'desccell'),
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbJEditableColumn',
            'jEditableOptions' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                // very important to get the attribute to update on the server!
                'submitdata' => array('attribute'=>'desc'),
                'cssclass' => 'form',
                'width' => '180px',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        )
    )
)
```

And this is my `getCssClass` code on `[root]/protected/models/Transaction.php`:

```
public function getCssClass(){
        $categoryType = Category::model()->findByPk($this->categoryId)->getAttribute("type");
        $categoryName = Category::model()->findByPk($this->categoryId)->getAttribute("name");

        $class = "";

        if($categoryName == "Uncategorized Income"){
            $class = "darkgreen";
        }
        else if($categoryName == "Uncategorized Expense"){
            return "darkred";
        }
        else if($categoryType == "INCOME"){
            return "green ";
        }
        else if($categoryType == "EXPENSE" || $categoryType == "COST OF GOODS"){
            return "red ";
        }
        else if($categoryType == "WITHDRAW" || $categoryType == "DEPOSIT" ){
            return "blue ";
        }
        else{
            return "grey ";
        }

        return $class . " " . $categoryName . " " . $categoryType;
    }
```

Comment: You will have to be pretty specific regarding how and why it's not working.

Comment: Well, I thought it supposed to be not working out of the box... since the inline edit is an ajax process while `rowCssClassExpression` is done on the server... What I wanna know is, how can I re-fire the function on `rowCssClassExpression` after Jeditable ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'afterAjaxUpdate' attribute to fire a javascript function on any update.

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' => ' function(){ //enterJScode }',
```